# What is the short hand for checking the result of this function?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm learning `Dart` and I understand that the below (should be) correct. I now want to understand how to do the shorthand version of this. This function lives in my state container (inherited widget) so that I can call this anywhere in my app. Hopefully calling this function everywhere in my app doesn't count as multiple Firestore queries...

```
String getUID() {
    final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid.toString();
    if (uid == null || uid == '') {
      return '';
    } else {
      return uid;  
    }    
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write it like this:

```dart
String getUID() {
    final String? uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid.toString();
  
    return uid ?? '';
}
```

or also as a getter (the getter won't need parentheses to be accessed **()**, you just call it as if it were an variable .uid):

```dart
String get uid => FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid ?? '';
```

The **??** operator will work as:

```dart
if(uid == null) {
 return ''; 
}

return uid;
```

You don't need to check for empty string **''** there because you are passing it as empty anyway.

Comment: Does your 2nd code block have a typo? Should it be `String getUID` instead of `String get uid`?

Comment: it`s not a typo it's a special method a "getter" here's the dart docs page that talk about it: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#getters-and-setters

Comment: If the answer is right could you mark it as the right answer? @whatwhatwhat

Answer (score 1):

You can write it like so

```
String getUID() => FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid ?? '';
```

There is no need for `toString()` as `uid` itself is already a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

how about make on `helper.dart`

- **helper.dart**  (or whatever you name it)

```
import 'the firebase package';
...
String getUID() {
    final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid.toString();
    if (uid == null || uid == '') {
      return '';
    } else {
      return uid;  
    }    
  }
```

then you can call `getUID` in every class

- eg: **home.dart**

```
import 'package:../helper.dart';

....
final _uid = getUID();
print(_uid);
....
```

im not sure this one is best solution, but this what i usually did for common function.